# Overload operators += and + Matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix, overloading

I'm having problems with overloading operators += and + in c++. I've got the following and I don't know why.. : "Invalid operands to binary expression (Matrice* and Matrice*) Do you have any ideas why ? Thanks.

NB : operator = does work.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std ;
#include "Matrice.hpp"


int main () {

double *tableau = new double[2*2]{1,4,3,2} ;
double *tableau1 = new double[2*2]{1,6,4,-2} ;
Matrice * A = new Matrice(2, tableau) ;
Matrice * B = new Matrice(2, tableau1) ;
Matrice * C = new Matrice() ;

C = A+B ;} // error appears here
```

## Matrice.cpp

```
#include "Matrice.hpp"

Matrice::Matrice(const Matrice& m) : dim(m.dim), coeffs(new         double[m.dim*m.dim]){
for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) {
    coeffs[i] = m.coeffs[i] ; 
}

}

Matrice::~Matrice() {
delete [] coeffs ;
}
```

## Matrice.hpp

```
#ifndef Matrice_hpp
#define Matrice_hpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class Matrice {
private :
unsigned int dim;
double * coeffs ;

public :
Matrice() {
    dim = 2 ;
    coeffs = new double[dim*dim] ;
    for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) {
        coeffs[i] = 0 ;
    }
}


Matrice(unsigned int n, double* v) : dim(n), coeffs(new double[dim*dim]) {
    if(v) { for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) { coeffs[i] = v[i] ;}
    }
    else { for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) coeffs[i] = 0 ; }
}

Matrice(const Matrice&) ;
~Matrice () ;

int dimension() const {return dim;}
void modifier(int position, int valeur) {coeffs[position] = valeur ; }


Matrice& operator= (const Matrice& m) {
    if(coeffs != m.coeffs) {
        delete [] coeffs ;
        dim = m.dim ;
        coeffs = new double[m.dim*m.dim] ;
        for(int i=0; i<m.dim*m.dim ; i++) {
            coeffs[i] = m.coeffs[i] ;
        }
    }

    return *this ;
}



Matrice& operator+=(const Matrice& m) {
    for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) {
        coeffs[i] += m.coeffs[i] ;
    }

    return *this ;
}

Matrice&operator+ (const Matrice& m)
{

    for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) {
        coeffs[i] = coeffs[i] + m.coeffs[i] ;
    }
    return *this ;
}



double* Coefficients() {return coeffs ;}
void Afficher() {
    for(int i=0; i<dim*dim; i++) {
        if (i%dim == 0) {cout << endl ; }
        cout << coeffs[i] << " "  ;
    }
    cout << endl ; 
}


};


#endif /* Matrice_hpp */
```

Comment: Don't use pointers and `new` for no reason.

Comment: Your overloads are for `Matrice`, not `Matrice*`.

Comment: don't use `new` _at all_

Comment: You should be returning a brand new `Matrice` for `operator +`, not a reference to the current `Matrice`.  Once you do that, then `operator +` simply becomes `{ return Matrice(*this) += m; }`.  However you seriously should be making sure (since you're using pointers), that your `Matrice` object has correct, non-buggy copy semantics before doing any operator overloading, and right now, the copy semantics are faulty.

Comment: *NB : operator = does work.* -- It won't work if `new` throws an exception.  Instead it would leave your current object in an unstable state.

Comment: I'll be a good person and show you how your class would look [if you quit using `new[]`](http://ideone.com/nwO0Y9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define operator in a class it can be used for instance of that class, not pointer. So if you change your code to:

```
Matrice A(2, tableau) ;
Matrice B(2, tableau1) ;
Matrice C = A + B;
```

it should work. You can also get similar effect dereferencing your pointers:

```
*C = *A + *B;
```

but there is no reason to use dynamically allocated objects in your code. For example you have memory leaks in your code as you do not have proper cleanup (delete statements).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add pointers. A, B and C are Pointers. 
To use Their operators, you need to dereference them.

```
*C = *A + *B
```

Would work.
 I haven't completly checked for any side effects, but this would allow your code to compile and run.

But your Pointer will be messed up.
A and C Would contain the same values. The coefs of are getting the values of B and then return a Pointer to A. 
C would then be a Pointer to B.
You will need to involve a new statement to make a true copy.

You will need to check this to avoid unwanted errors.

Comment: The purpose of a class is to make the public interface understandable.  If I had to use a Matrix class like this `C = &(*A + *B);` to add `A + B`, I would go nuts.